# Dynamic Pivot Counts TSQL to flatten results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a normalized table that I'd like to 'Flatten' dynamically.

Picture below for example input and output. The columns need to be fetched dynamically, it can't be hard coded.
[image: IO]

So far, this is what I'm working on.

```
`DECLARE @Query nvarchar(MAX) = '';`

DECLARE @columns nvarchar(1000) = '';`

Select @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(Food) + ',' FROM (select distinct Food from tblPeopleFoods ) as tmp

Select @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols))
```

At this point, I have the properly comma separated string for my column names.

I'm hung up on the `PIVOT` query to flag each person 1 or 0 for having each food.

This is what I have so far

```
set @query =

'SELECT * from

(

    select Person, Food from tblPeopleFoods

) src

pivot

(

  count(*)   for Person in (' + @cols + ')

) piv
```

Comment: This has been asked and answered dozens and dozens of times.

Comment: [[sql-server\] Dynamic Pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+dynamic+pivot). Pick and choose your answer from the results

Comment: @SeanLange In the examples I've seen, they are pivoting values, not flagging whether it exists

Comment: If there's a count of 1 (or more) it exists. That's still a Pivot.

Comment: I figured it out. I just needed to add derive a column in the source of the pivot, just a '1' , and then just count/sum that field in the pivot clause

Comment: Yeah same concept, just need to add an aggregate. Glad you got it sorted.